# Why I can upload only one file at a time with multi upload widget?

Tags: 7, files

I have installed the multi-upload widget module to be able to upload several files at once. I have set a file widget to multi upload, which has enabled the ability to choose several files at once however only one files uploads are there any necessary module to install for the module to work ?

Thanks for any help on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you are using APC for upload progress:

[image: Your server is capable of displaying file upload progress using APC RFC1867. Note that only one upload at a time is supported. It is recommended to use the PECL uploadprogress library if possible.]

Check your status report to see. If so, do what it suggest. Or ask / pay your sysadmin to do it.